# On operator ranges in Hilbert & Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Lemma 1 from [Anderson & Trapp's Shorted Operators, II](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2100462) is

> Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded operators on the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.  The following statements are equivalent:

(1) ran($A$) $\subset$ ran($B$).

(2) $AA^* \le \lambda^2 BB^*$ for some $\lambda \ge 0$.

(3) There exists a bounded operator $C$ such that $A = BC$.

Moreover, if (1), (2) and (3) are satisfied, there exists a unique operator $C$ so that ker($A$) = ker($C)$ and ran($C$) $\subset$ closure(ran($B^*$)).They follow this with the statement, "the lemmas and the original proofs remain valid for operators between two Hilbert spaces."

**Question:**I would like to know if there is a similar statement for more general Banach spaces, and if so, where I might find it.

**My context:**  I am considering the Banach space $\Omega = C(U_1) \times C(U_2)$ of continuous functions over two domains.  I have a covariance operator $$K : \Omega^* \to \Omega$$
which is decomposed as $$K = \binom{K_{11} ~ K_{12}}{K_{21} ~ K_{22}}.$$  I want to apply the above lemma to $A = K_{21}$ and $B = K_{22}^{1/2}$.

**Edit:**  If we have a probability measure $\mathbb P$ on $\Omega$, then continuous linear functionals $\Omega^*$ are random variables.  Thus the expectation $\mathbb Efg$ for $f, g \in \Omega^*$ is well-defined.  The covariance operator is the bilinear form defined by $f(Kg) = \mathbb Efg$.

Comment: What is the norm on $C(U_1)\times C(U_2)$?  Just the maximum, so that we really get $C(U_1 \cup U_2)$, the continuous functions on the disjoint union of $U_1$ and $U_2$?  Then $\Omega^*$ is the $\ell_1$ sum of $M(U_1)$ with $M(U_2)$.  So I don't understand your "edit"...

Comment: @Matt, yes.  I'm looking at continuous functions over a union $C(U \cup V)$ where $U$ and $V$ are compact planar regions, and considering the sup norm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) does not generally imply (3) for bounded operators between Banach spaces. The first example I have a reference for was due to Douglas and was included in ["Factorization of operators on Banach space"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2038955) by Embry in 1973.  That paper has much more that might interest you, such as the fact that a factorization holds when you have the reverse range inclusion of the adjoints.

See also: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2043114

Comment: +1 because that reference might plug in as part of background to something I've been toying with on and off for the last 5 years :)

Comment: Jonas, thank you for the reference.  This answers my question in the negative.  Now I need to figure a way to make it work for a *positive* operator K.

Comment: You're welcome.  Funny thing about the second link: The preview page is the entire article, but if you click on it without a subscription to JSTOR you are invited to buy it for 24 USD.

Answer (score 6):

One way to reformulate (1) as a factorization result is this:

Suppose $S:X\to Z$ and $T:Y\to Z$ are bounded linear operators and $SX\subset TX$.  Then $S$ factors through the map $T$ induces from $Y/T^{-1}(0)$ into $Z$. To see this, WLOG $T$ and $S$ are one to one, and just observe that by e.g. the closed graph theorem $SX\subset TX$ implies that for some $a$,  $SB_X \subset aTB_Y$.

Of course, this implies that  if $T^{-1}(0)$ is complemented in $Y$, then $S$ factors through $T$ itself.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: but this is vaguely reminiscent of some of the setup in Waelbroeck's "Quotient Banach spaces" series of papers - which I believe you referred to on some other question?

Comment: IIRC Waelbroeck's set up was more complicated and he added morphisms to make the categorical aspects nicer.  

Comment: That sounds right - it was his version of something done by Guy Noel, I think, & meant to be *more* to the taste of functional analysts...

Answer (score 1):

My initial impression is that for what you want, you're going to need a notion of $A^*: E\to E$ when $A:E\to E$ is an operator on a Banach space. I don't know much about this, but some years ago did see this short paper

> MR2053349 (2005a:46045)
>
> Gill, Tepper L.(1-HWRD-EE); Basu, Sudeshna(1-HWRD); Zachary, Woodford W.(1-HWRD-EE); Steadman, V.(1-DC)
>
> Adjoint for operators in Banach spaces. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 132 (2004), no. 5, 1429--1434

which requires a choice of Hilbert space rigging $H_1 \hookrightarrow E \hookrightarrow H_2$.

One thing that might go wrong with $(1) \implies (3)$ in general Banach spaces is the non-existence, in general, of projections from $E$ onto a closed subspace. However, that doesn't rule out the possiblity that something like $(1)\implies(3)$ does indeed hold; I'd need to think about this a bit more.

**Edit:** ah, I see that in your setting the operators go from one Banach space to another, rather than from the space to itself. That might make a difference: and indeed, since you're mapping into a $C(K)$-space and not just an arbitrary one, more tools might be available.

Comment: @Yemon, thanks for the fast response.  In this context, K is an operator from Omega* to Omega.  I neglected to write that because I'm still trying to wrap my head around this functional analytic point of view!  If I do everything by the abstract Wiener space construction, then there is the Hilbert-Schmidt subspace to take advantage of, so the Hilbert space rigging actually arises quick naturally.  (1) => (3) is in fact the direction I am trying to prove.  Thanks!

Comment: (quite not quick)

Comment: I meant Cameron-Martin, not Hilbert-Schmidt.  You can tell I was in a rush when I wrote that comment.  @Yemon, that's a really enlightening paper.  Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

In Embry's 1973 and Douglas' 1966 papers the Hilbert space condition $AA^* < \lambda^2 BB^*$ about the adjoints is replaced by the following equivalent Banach type of condition: $\|A\| < \lambda \|B\|$, so that the whole exotic question of Banach space adjoints $A^* : X \to X$ analogous to Hilbert space adjoints is avoided.

On the other hand, if $A:X \to Y$, the Banach space adjoint defined as $A^* : Y^* \to X^*$ using duality theory does play an important role in the results of Douglas and Embry. Embry's is accessible on the free internet and is easy to read.